# Unable to import a case class in an abstract class

Tags: scala

I want to run the class Expr below. I've taken this code from http://andymaleh.blogspot.ie/2008/04/scalas-pattern-matching-visitor-pattern.html

Here is what I am trying :

```
import Expr.Sum

object Main {

    def main(args:Array[String]) {

      var expr1 = new Sum(new Num(1), new Prod(new Num(2), new Num(3)))
      print(expr1)
  }

}

abstract class Expr {

  case class Num(n: Int) extends Expr
  case class Sum(l: Expr , r: Expr) extends Expr
  case class Prod(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

  def evalExpr(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Num(n) => n
    case Sum(l, r) => evalExpr(l) + evalExpr(r)
    case Prod(l, r) => evalExpr(l) * evalExpr(r)
  }

  def printExpr(e: Expr) : Unit = e match {
    case Num(n) => print(" " + n + " ")
    case Sum(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("+"); printExpr(r)
    case Prod(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("x"); printExpr(r)
  }

}
```

But line

```
import Expr.Sum
```

is causing a compile time error : 'not found: object Expr' . How can I import the class Expr ?

Comment: do these definitions come from different files? are they in the same package? details please.

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup ive updated my question to show the original source of the code.

Comment: @user701254 The code at that link is the same as what I answered minus some curly braces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only import members of instances. So your code would be:

```
object Main {
    def main(args:Array[String]) {
      val expr = new Expr {} // now we have a instance.

      import expr._
      var expr1 = new Sum(new Num(1), new Prod(new Num(2), new Num(3)))
      print(expr1)
  }
}
```

A simple example explains why you can't import non-instances members:

```
class A(val x:Int) {
  object Print { def print = println(x) }
}
```

If you could `import A.Print`, which value would be bound to `x`? Now if we do:

```
val a = new A(5); // we have a value bound to x.
import a._
Print.print
```

This is one reason. The other reason that `new A(5).Print != new A(5).Print`, not only in equality, but also in type: `val (a1, a2) = (new A(5), new A(5)); implicitly[a1.Print <:< a2.Print]` wouldn't compile. This is what Scala calls *path-dependent types*.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the case classes out of the abstract class gets it to compile. They are also in the same scope in this case so there is nothing to import.

Also note that an `import` error isn't applicable here since `Main` and `Expr` are defined in the same package. i.e. the default package.

```
object Main {    
    def main(args:Array[String]) {

      var expr1 = new Sum(new Num(1), new Prod(new Num(2), new Num(3)))
      print(expr1)
  }
}

abstract class Expr {
}

case class Num(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Sum(l: Expr , r: Expr) extends Expr
case class Prod(l: Expr, r: Expr) extends Expr

def evalExpr(e: Expr): Int = e match {
  case Num(n) => n
  case Sum(l, r) => evalExpr(l) + evalExpr(r)
  case Prod(l, r) => evalExpr(l) * evalExpr(r)
}

def printExpr(e: Expr) : Unit = e match {
  case Num(n) => print(" " + n + " ")
  case Sum(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("+"); printExpr(r)
  case Prod(l, r) => printExpr(l); print("x"); printExpr(r)
}
```

Running this gives:

```
scala>Main.main(Array[String]())
Sum(Num(1),Prod(Num(2),Num(3)))
```

Comment: Does not work because you are not allowed to have top-level-defs. Wrap them in `object Expr` or something like that.